# About the local path & hdfs path when loading data to Hive

Tags: hive

I'm learning Hive's DML operations. 
  In this tutorial https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-RunningHive

there is a example,

```
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH './examples/files/kv1.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE pokes;
```

1. I want to ask what does the current path "./" refer to in this case?

And there is another example,

```
hive> LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/myname/kv2.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE invites PARTITION (ds='2008-08-15');
```

2. It said Hive loads data from hdfs in this case, then I am confused about what is the root path of hdfs on local file system?

Answer (score -1):

It means starting from your home directory in the local path. You have to have the hdfs dfs prefix to each command to move stuff in the hdfs path.